# AWS dynamodb Query crashes most of the time

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

i'm trying to download user data from AWS DynamoDB like this:

```
func downloadUserData(id: String) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true

    let qe = AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression()
    qe.hashKeyAttribute = "id"
    qe.hashKeyValues = id

    dynamoDBObjectMapper!.query(DDBUser.self, expression: qe).continueWithBlock { (task: AWSTask) -> AnyObject? in
        if task.error != nil {
            NSLog("\(self)")
            NSLog("Fehler beim Laden der Userdaten: \(task.error)")
        } else {
            let paginatedOutput = task.result as! AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput
            print("output \(paginatedOutput.items)")
            for user in paginatedOutput.items as! [DDBUser] {
                SessionController.sharedInstance.user = user
                for (index, tacklId) in SessionController.sharedInstance.user.tacklIds.enumerate() {
                    if tacklId == "empty" {
                        SessionController.sharedInstance.user.tacklIds.removeAtIndex(index)
                    }
                }
                if !(SessionController.sharedInstance.user.endpoints.contains(SessionController.sharedInstance.currEndpoint!)) {
                    SessionController.sharedInstance.user.endpoints += [SessionController.sharedInstance.currEndpoint!]
                }
            }
            NSLog("User Download Complete")
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
                self.userdataDelegate?.userdataDownloadComplete!()
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Not alway, but most of the time, the Execution stops at this line:

```
 for user in paginatedOutput.items as! [DDBUser] {
```

With this Error code:

```
exc_breakpoint (code=1, subcode=0x10015d440)
```

It even happens with Breakpoints disabled and i can't continue with the Execution.

The line before the break:

```
print("output \(paginatedOutput.items)")
```

works well. Could the problem be on another thread and it falsely shows me the error here? How to best debug this? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use

```
let qe = AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression()
qe.hashKeyAttribute = "id"
qe.hashKeyValues = id
```

which is deprecated. I would suggest you use 'keyConditionExpression' and 'expressionAttributeValues' instead.

Thanks,
Rohan